# Updating unique instance of a group of rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a UID field, an "in study" field (which will take either 0 or 1), and a text field. There are many duplicates in the text field. So far I have figured out a way to select only the first instance of the text field:

```
select "text.original", min(UID) from tblHashtags group by "text.original" order by min(UID);
```

What I really want, however, is a one-liner that will update the "in study" field in all the records returned above to 1. And then it would be very nice to be able to invert this selection to update all other records to 0 as well. I am probably missing something simple but I don't play around with SQL very often, unfortunately.

Edit to add: Having worked on this some more, I would be grateful for assistance in just doing this, nevermind the one-liner. The best I can do so far is:

```
update tblHashtags set "instudy"=1 where (select "text.original", min(UID) from tblHashtags group by "text.original" order by min(UID));
Error: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the text.original column which will result in a single-column result set being returned. You can use a single-column result set in an IN clause.

```
UPDATE tblHashtags SET "instudy" = 1 WHERE UID IN (
    SELECT UID FROM tblHashtags GROUP BY "text.original" ORDER BY min(UID)
);
```

Comment: Many thanks! "You can use a single-column result set in an IN clause" is definitely a tidbit to tuck away.